# WPF: How to make textblock fire key event?

Tags: wpf, events, key, textblock

TextBlock has KeyDown and KeyUp event, but it's never fired. Is there a way to make it happen?  I just need to detect if any key is pressed.

Comment: **KeyDown** and **KeyUp** events will be fired if your **TextBlock** will get a **KeyboardFocus**.

Comment: I can't find KeyboardFocus on TextBlock. Do you mean Focusable = true and then call textBlock.Focus()?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all you will need to set the [`Focusable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.focusable.aspx) Property of your TextBlock to True, This will allow you to Tab to the Item but not Click to select it, but if you handle the MouseDown Event you can manualy set Focus to your TextBlock.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid >
       <TextBlock Name="tb1"  Height="30" Width ="100" IsEnabled="True"  Focusable="True" KeyDown="tb1_KeyDown" MouseDown="tb1_MouseDown">Hello World</TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void tb1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        tb1.Background = Brushes.Blue;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        tb1.Focus();
    }

    private void tb1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        tb1.Focus();
    }
}
```