# Both MouseDown and KeyDown event is not fired even though Focusable is set to true

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm trying to get my textblock to fire some events, and [the resource here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13577585/3834) says that:

> First of all you will need to set the Focusable Property of your
>   TextBlock to True, This will allow you to Tab to the Item but not
>   Click to select it, but if you handle the MouseDown Event you can
>   manually set Focus to your TextBlock.

That was what I did with the following  (slightly modified)sample:

**XAML code ( MainWindow.xaml)**

```
<Window x:Class="databinding_tutorial.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Personal Details"
        Height="180"
        Width="250"
        ResizeMode="NoResize">
    <Grid Margin="5" Name="gridName">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBlock>First Name</TextBlock>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Margin="5 0 0 5"/>

        <TextBlock Name="LastNameTB" Grid.Row="1" KeyDown="LastNameTB_KeyDown" Focusable="True" MouseDown="LastNameTB_MouseDown">Last Name</TextBlock>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="5 0 0 5"/>

        <TextBlock Name="AgeTB" Grid.Row="2">Age</TextBlock>
        <StackPanel Name="stackPan" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Margin="5 0 0 5">
            <Slider Minimum="16" Maximum="120" />
            <TextBlock Name="stackPanTB" Text="16" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" HorizontalAlignment="Right">New Window</Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
  /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/WPFDataContext.aspx
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
            var ageName = AgeTB.Text;
        }



        private void LastNameTB_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            var ageName = AgeTB.Text;
            LastNameTB.Background = Brushes.Blue;

        }



        private void LastNameTB_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            LastNameTB.Focus();
        }
    }
```

In my case here, neither the `MouseDown` nor the `KeyDown` event is fired... any reason?

Comment: The MouseDown event should be fired but the TextBlock doesn't fire any KeyDown events even if you focus it. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You added events for textblocks not for textbox , Events will work for textblock

**Remove and add events to TextBox**

```
<TextBlock Name="LastNameTB" Grid.Row="1" >Last Name</TextBlock>
<TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="5 0 0 5" KeyDown="LastNameTB_KeyDown" Focusable="True" MouseDown="LastNameTB_MouseDown"/>
```

Comment: That was so obvious with the benefit of hindsight. Thanks!